# What do the rectangles surrounding text mean in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2

As I'm typing in a Ruby file, I noticed that some rectangles pop up around some of the text I'm typing and often stays there:

[image]

Any idea what it means? Can I turn this annoying feature off?

Comment: Are you using [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter)?

Comment: Ah, SublimeLinter, no, but https://github.com/lunixbochs/sublimelint...now I'm wondering which one is cooler! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm, nice, these are actually blocks indicating possible code errors / syntax errors. When your caret is inside one of these blocks, it shows the error in the Sublime Text status bar.

Not sure if this is native, or due to some plugin I installed.

Comment: "Not sure if this is native, or due to some plugin I installed." -see my comment in your question.